# imagemin dist is not working properly

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, grunt-usemin, jhipster

i have working on project using grunt.i am getting this exception while running project using grunt with mvn.

Warning: Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Warning: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs' Use --force to continue.

can any one help me?.

Thanks advance.

Comment: It seems your `npm` project installation is corrupt. Check if your `package.json` has a `devDependency` for grunt-contrib-imagemin (or an alternative), remove `node_modules` directory and re-execute `npm install` in the project dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that, one more time, "imagemin" has released a new unstable version. This is not the first time.

If this is confirmed, I will block all Grunt dependencies in our package.json (no more "~"). We have done the same thing with Bower, as everybody is always releasing buggy versions all the time...